# iphone certificates

Tags: iphone

hey 
i'm beginner to iphone and as well in development field...
i want to make certificate to distribute my app on appstore...
can any one help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Managing Devices and Digital Identities](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices_and_Digital_Identities/devices_and_identities.html) and [Publishing Your Application for Distribution](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH10-SW21)